# How to add column in admin sales order grid magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-grid

I want to add SKU column, customer first name and last name in admin sales order grid.
Please guide me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

This is the way to achieve  that:

[Add column to sales order grid.](https://medium.com/@sivaschenko/magento-2-adding-a-column-to-the-sales-order-grid-fca2f62c0b0c)

Comment: Both links are 404ing. Which is why SE asks you to answer the question, not just add links.

Comment: Link has been updated. Working fine now.